# Creating a horizontal legend with labels in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, legend, getlegendgraphic

Im am trying to ask GeoServer for a horizontally orientated colorbar legend for my raster layer. I prepared an SLD style for the layer and asked for the legend with the GetLegendGraphic method, including: legend_options=layout:horizontal in the request.
The result is indeed a horizontal legend, but with its labels rotated and above the color bar. 
What I am after is just a horizontal color bar with the labels beneath it.
What am I missing?

My server request is:
http://localhost:8090/geoserver/wms?REQUEST=GetLegendGraphic&VERSION=1.0.0&FORMAT=image/png&WIDTH=50&HEIGHT=30&LAYER=Sacstests:S5P_NRTI_L2__NO2____20190401_latlon_0.500000&legend_options=layout:horizontal

The results (with and without the horizontal option) are included below. As you can see, the whole legend has rotated, including the labels, wereas I would like the labels to stay upright, and be placed below the colorbar.

[image: Horizontal legend version]

[image: Vertical legend version]

Comment: can you add the legend images to your question

Comment: Sure. I have updated the post.